# Django custom Authentication get_user() error

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

The views.py

```
def login_form_student(request):
    
    if request.method =='POST':
        roll_no = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('pass')

        user = authenticate(request, uniq_id=roll_no,password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request,user)
            return redirect('/userdetails/prof_page/')
        else:
            return redirect('/userdetails/thankyoupage/')


    return render(request,'user_interaction/login_form.html')
```

The custom backend

```
from .models import user_detail
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend

class user_auth_custom(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self,request,uniq_id,password):
        flag = 0
        try:
             user = user_detail.objects.get(roll_no=uniq_id)
             if password == user.password:
                 flag = 1
                 return user
        except flag == 0:
            pass
        return None
    
    def get_user(self,user_id):
        try:
            return user_detail.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except user_detail.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

The models.py

```
class user_detail(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=264,null=True)
    roll_no = models.CharField(max_length=264,unique=True,primary_key=True)
    management_name = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    contact_no = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    residential_status = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=32,default='fmspsg2020')
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I get a Validation Error.
['“18pw13” value must be an integer.']
18pw13 is actually a roll_no.

What should i do?
Should i create a new user_id attribute to the model of IntegerField?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just inherit the user model from djangos AbstactBaseUser, it makes it alot easier, because you get all the user functionallity that the Django user provides.

Here is a link:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model

Comment: There is a some good youtube videos available showing how to do this as well.

Comment: i thought that i will only have one super user. I really wanted to use my own custom model rather than the default model.So pls help.

Comment: Because i am having two types of users for this project.So i created a similar model for the other type of users.I jus want to authenticate this properly.

Comment: Also if i use a abstract model, I dont have to write custom auth for tht?

Comment: It is perfectly possible to have multiple different usermodels who inherit AbstractUser, and there are tutorials about it if you seach the web.
Maybe ask yourself if it is really necessary so have 2 different usermodels for your project, or if you just need to set some switches in your custom model which fits the different types. 

superuser, admin, staff and regular users are all the default usertypes in Django, but they are all the same userModel, what makes them different is just a simple boolean value attribute in the model.

I hope it helps, and good luck with the project.

Comment: woah.Yeah u are right i could just have same model and then use boolean attributes.Thank u.